# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ChemmineOB’

Tags: r, compilation

```
ChemmineOB.cpp:1569:10: fatal error: openbabel/obutil.h: No such file or directory
 1569 | #include <openbabel/obutil.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: ChemmineOB.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ChemmineOB’
* removing ‘/home/mamata/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/ChemmineOB’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpzscekt/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘ChemmineOB’ had non-zero exit status
```

i am trying to install ChemmineOB and I get the this error. I have openbabel installed in the system already. Can anyone help?